# Why is $R((X))$ defined as follows?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $R$ be a commutative ring.

Then $R((X))$ is defined as the set of all $\sum_{n\geq N} a_n X_n$ where $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ and is called "The Formal Laurent series". But why?

Why don't we consider the monoid ring $R[\mathbb{Z}]$ instead? I think $R[\mathbb{Z}]$ deserves to be called " the Formal laurent series" since it seems useful to interpret (Formal) Fourier series, and cannot understand why $R((X))$ deserves that name.

Moreover, is there a standard notation for the monoid ring $R[\mathbb{Z}]$?

Comment: The monoid ring should be called the ring of Laurent *polynomials*.  It's what you get from the polynomial ring by adjoining a multiplicative inverse for $X$.  The ring of formal Laurent *series* is what you get from the ring of formal power series by adjoining a multiplicative inverse for $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Edit after a bit more research:)* Another widespread notation for $R[\Bbb Z]$ is $R\Bbb Z$. The latter may be preferable if one wants to avoid confusion with the polynomial ring in either a single variable $\Bbb Z$ or the polynomial ring in countably many variables (that happen to be integers, but cannot be added or multiplied as such); then again, for some rings $R$, $R\Bbb Z$ might in some contexts be confused with the complex product $\{\,rz\mid r\in R, z\in\Bbb Z\,\}$, which is not the same (e.g., the complex product $\Bbb Z\Bbb Z$ is just $\Bbb Z$)

All of $R[X]$, $R[[X]]$, $R((X))$, $R[\Bbb Z]$ (and possibly more) have their own applications and hence their own justification. 
Note that $R[\Bbb Z]$ is (via the obvious embedding) in fact a small subring of $R((X))$, essentially it equals $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}X^{-n}R[X]$ (just to emphasize that there are only finitely many non-zero coefficients) or simply $R[X,X^{-1}]\subsetneq R((X))$.

On the other hand, we cannot use (what you may have had in mind actually) $R^\Bbb Z$, the set of all maps $\Bbb Z\to R$ (or if you want a series-like notation: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nX^n$) because for general $R$ this allows only addition, but not multiplication (at least not Cauchy-product-like). If $R$ carries a topology, we *may* be able to define the Cauchy product of two such series for some cases; we may even be able to pinpoint a suitable subgroup that *happens* to be closed under multiplication - but that is in no way a general approach.

Comment: Hm, I assume the downvote is because I did not restate the formal definitions of all those constructs?

Comment: +1 for guessing that the OP might have meant $R^{\mathbb Z}$, since that seems closer to Fourier series than $R[\mathbb Z]$.  Perhaps part of the moral of the story should be that there's no good ring of formal Fourier series --- Fourier theory really needs some convergence.

Comment: Minor quibble: apart from very specific cases, I'd say the most frequent notation for Laurent polynomials is more probably $R[X,X^{-1}]$ (which you also mention) than $R[\mathbb{Z}]$. Without a comment, I'd be puzzled if I saw "$R[\mathbb{Z}]$". Incidentally, it's perhaps useful to point out that $k(\!(X,Y)\!)$ is also not the same as $k(\!(X)\!)(\!(Y)\!)$ (I'm not sure the former even means anything unless $k$ is a field).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh yes. I meant $R^\mathbb{Z}$. I misthought.